# PHP: Why does usort() set some of my array elements to null

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I try to sort my 2-dimensional array with usort().

My cmp() function looks like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $columnName = 'StyleNo';

    $paramA = str_replace(array("-", "."), "", $a[$columnName]);
    $paramB = str_replace(array("-", "."), "", $b[$columnName]);

    if(empty($paramA) || empty($paramB)){
        return 0;
    }

    if($paramA > $paramB){
        return -1;
    } else if($paramA < $paramB){
        return 1;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

which i call by:

```
usort($data, "cmp");
```

From my understanding cmp() will always return either 1, 0 or -1.
However, my array $data will have some array elements set to null after the call to cmp().

How can that be?

Note: 'StyleNo' is a key in the inner arrays of my nested array and exists in all inner arrays.

EDIT:
I noticed this happens for arrays of more than 400 elements.

Comment: Please give us an [mcve] with an example array.

Comment: ^ Please edit post adding original and resulting array

Comment: There is nothing in the `cmp()` function that modifies its input, and if there was, you should get an error when you called `usort` that the comparison function was modifying the array. It seems like the null setting must be happening somewhere else. Can you provide a bit of the context where that `usort` is used?

Comment: I was a little mistaken. You wouldn't get an error, but you would get a warning: "Warning: usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function".

Comment: I think the only way for the `cmp` function to be able to modify the array you are sorting is if `$a` or `$b` were references or if you used `global` in the function.

Comment: @Don't Panic I don't get any warning, but probably this depends on the configuration of PHP.

Comment: That's true. At any rate, the `$a` and `$b` in the `cmp` function are copies of your array elements in the scope of that function, not the actual elements.